# Can't loop over array in AngularJS template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Running in to a frustrating issue with AngularJS. All I'm trying to do is load a json file and display it in the template using ng:repeat. I've not had any issue with this in the past but for some reason, the code below doesn't work. Can someone take a look and tell me what I'm missing?

If you look at the template:

**palette.html**

```
{{palette}}

<div ng-repeat="for color in palette">{{color}}</div>
```

`{{palette}}` outputs `[{"hex":"#6e4516"},{"hex":"#DDDABE"},{"hex":"#ECEAD9"},{"hex":"#98A349"},{"hex":"#798616"}]` however the ng:repeat displays nothing. So the json is being loaded in to the scope but for some reason I can't loop over it.

Here is my main js file:

**app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('App', []).
    config(function($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/palette', {templateUrl:'templates/palette.html', controller:PaletteController}).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'})
    });

function PaletteController($scope, $http){
    $http.get('palette.json').success(function(palette){
        $scope.palette = palette;
    });
}
```

and the data being loaded from the json file:

**palette.json**

```
[
    {"hex": "#6e4516"},
    {"hex": "#DDDABE"},
    {"hex": "#ECEAD9"},
    {"hex": "#98A349"},
    {"hex": "#798616"}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're code within the expression section of ng-repeat is incorrect. You need something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in palette">{{color.hex}}</div>
```

Comment: That's what I get for working on a python project at the same time. Thanks, it was driving me nuts!